# Querying a ManyToMany Field in a Django model

Tags: python, database, django, models

So I have these two models:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    playerName = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    playerTeam = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Role(models.Model):
    roleName = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player)
```

Now, storing different players under one role was easy. My aim is to retrieve distinct 'playerTeam' under one role. To make it clear, I want the values of the different teams in string format. So, if two Player object is stored as:

```
p = Player(playerName='Zidane', playerTeam = 'Real Madrid') 
p1 = Player(playerName='Laudrup', playerTeam = 'Barcelona')
```

and both are added to one Role object, say:

```
r = Role(roleName='playmaker')
r.save()
r.add(p)
r.add(p1)
r.save()
```

I want to write a query which will give me 'Real Madrid' and 'Barcelona' as results.

Writing the query for it is proving to be a challenge. Any help I can get?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: @themanatuf I have read through the docs. The query that I'm looking for, isn't given.

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony I have tried to write a query to get these two values in a list, but am failing to do so.

Comment: What is your query? You said what you want it to return, but never really stated what the actual query is. Are you trying to find the teams for all playmakers?

Comment: You may want to consider changing your models. I would think a player can have a role, not a role can have players. It seems a bit backwards which may be why you're having trouble.

Comment: @themanatuf No a single role can have N number of players who play that role. And yes, I'm trying to find the different teams for all playmakers.

Comment: If that's the case then try: `Player.objects.filter(role__exact='playmaker')`. Disclaimer: I haven't tried it, going from memory.

Comment: Sorry, I think it's `Player.objects.filter(role__roleName__exact='playmaker')`

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
r.players.values_list('playerTeam', flat=True)
```

Where `r` is the Role for which you want to get the teams.

If you want to get distinct teams, just put the result in a `set()`.